# Haskell: should I use Data.Text.Lazy.Builder to construct my Text values?

Tags: haskell, text

I'm working on a large application that constructs a lot of `Data.Text` values on the fly. I've been building all my `Text` values using `(<>)` and `Data.Text.concat`.

I only recently learned of the existence of the [`Builder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.0.5/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html) type. The [Beginning Haskell](http://www.apress.com/9781430262503) book has this to say about it:

> Every time two elements are concatenated, a new `Text` value has to be created, and this comes with some overhead to allocate memory, to copy data, and also to keep track of the value and release it when it's no longer needed... Both the `text` and `bytestring` packages provide a `Builder` data type that can be used to **efficiently generate large text values**. [pg 240]

However, the book doesn't give any indication of exactly what is meant by "large text values."

So, I'm wondering whether or not I should refactor my code to use `Builder`. Maybe you can help me make that decision.
Specifically, I have these questions:

1) Are there any guidelines or "best practices" regarding when one should choose `Builder` over concatenation? Or, how do I know that a given `Text` value is "large" enough that it merits using `Builder`?

2) Is using `Builder` a "no brainer," or would it be worthwhile doing some profiling to confirm its benefits before undertaking a large-scale refactoring?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Data.Text.concat` is an `O(n+m)` operation where `n` and `m` are the lengths of the strings you want to `concat`. This is because a new memory buffer of size `n + m` must be allocated to store the result of the concatenation.

`Builder` is specifically optimized for the `mappend` operation. It's a cheap `O(1)` operation (function composition, which is also excellently optimized by GHC). With `Builder` you are essentially building up the *instructions* for how to produce the final string result, but delaying the actual creation until you do some `Builder -> Text` transformation.

To answer your questions, you should choose `Builder` if you have profiled your application and discovered that `Text.concat` are dominating the run time. This will obviously depend on your needs and application. There is no general rule for when you should use `Builder` but for short `Text` literals there is probably no need.

Profiling would definitely be worthwhile if using `Builder` would involve "undertaking a large-scale refactoring". Although it goes without saying that Haskell will naturally make this kind of refactoring much less painful than you might be used to with less developer friendly languages, so it might not be such a difficult undertaking after all.